# Email monitoring in an infinite while loop. Any downsides/ better ideas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, while-loop, imaplib

I am writing a short script to monitor my inbox and get notified at every new incoming email. So far, I am using an infinite while loop like this:

```
msg_id_check = None
while True:
    result, data = mail.fetch(mail.select('INBOX')[1][0], "(RFC822)")  # mail is an imaplib object
    msg_str = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    msg_id = get_email_id(msg_str.get('Received'))
    if msg_id == msg_id_check:  # Don't keep notifying me of the same email
        continue
    FROM = msg_str.get('From')
    SUBJECT = msg_str.get('Subject')
    BODY = get_body(msg_str).decode()
    print(f"Subject: {SUBJECT}\nFrom: {FROM}\nBody: {BODY}")
    msg_id_check = msg_id
```

I first thought that I couldm't do this, because I've heard my computer when it gets stuck in an infinite loop and it does not sound like it enjoys it, but when I tried this code I didn't hear any noises from my computer, so I am wondering, is this a cpu-friendly process or is there a better way of getting notified at every incoming email?

P.S. Right now I am just printing new emails out to the screen, but in my project I need to do things with these emails and I do not want to lose any of these emails.

Comment: The email host might hate you as you are checking repeatedly as fast as the server can respond. I would recommend adding a time.sleep(300) in there or something so you check only every 5 minutes or some reasonable interval.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request your program does't go further without awnser (can be timeout) so you have a "buffer" in your while loop but you don't need to know each second if you have a new mail you should put a `time.sleep(60)` at the end of the loop to send less useless requests